# Preprocessor directive's confusing terminology

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am confused about the words:

**Pre-processor directive**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

puts("It's me, your first program.");

return 0;

}
```

When the preprocessor meets that directive, it replaces the directive with the content of the file whose name is listed in the directive (in our case, this is the file named stdio.h).

Shouldn't some proper name been given to the terminology than directive - **because directive seems to me that it directs the file rather than replaces it.**

Comment: directive, n, An official or authoritative instruction. If that instruction is `#define`, then it will do one thing. If it is `#include`, then something else will happen.

Comment: _because directive seems to me that it directs the file rather than replaces it._ -- it directs the preprocessor, not the file. There are more preprocessor directives than just `#include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other preprocessor directives, for example:

```
 #define MAXLEN 256
```

The word "directive" here means the source code line is directing the C preprocessor to do something.

And, as for understanding the Byzantine layers of jargon complexity in a widely adopted language that's well over a generation old, well, everybody struggles with that.

Comment: ok so I do understand - Directing it to replace! now that makes it understandable - thanks so so much or as you say Define (obviously a direction)